# change text of button when i click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

change text of button when i click it. when i click on the button if it show make it hide .

```js
  $(function () {
    if ($(".clickMe").text() == 'show') {

      $(".clickMe").text("hide")
    }
    else {

      $(".clickMe").text("show")
    }
  });
```

```html
<a href="#" class="clickMe">ShowDetials</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Bind an event to it first, i meant a click event

```
$(".clickMe").click(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).text() == "show" ? "hide" : "show");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5bgjqmk6/)

Comment: At first, button text is `ShowDetials` and `"ShowDetials" != "show"` so it will be no effect when clicking it first time

Comment: @Justinas I just edited the markup as well.. can you check the demo once.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this

Html

```
<a href="#" class="clickMe">show</a>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $('.clickMe').click(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).text() == "show" ? "hide" : "show");
     });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoj/2vtgpLec/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to apply some attribute (like class) to indicate state of button. Also, when you click on link, browser will follow it, prevent that (if needed effect). And your function is fired only once when everything is loaded, but not when clicking element. Bind click event to element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent from following link.

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this)
        .removeClass('active')
        .text('Show Details');
    } else {
      $(this)
        .addClass('active')
        .text('Hide Details');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #454545;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com" class="btn">Show Details</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

All purpose function

HTML part

```
<button type="submit" onclick="changeText(this,'Checking.. Please wait...')">Login</button>
```

JS part

```
// function to change text
function changeText(ref,text){
   ref.innerHTML = text;
}
```